# How to pass multiple values to one SSRS parameter programmatically (VB.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I need to pass multiple values to one SSRS parameter programmatically (VB.NET, C#). e.g. several counties to a report parameter called "country". This can be easily done manually ba defining the parameter as multi valued parameter and choosing multiple parameter values by activating the checkboxes of the parameter at runtime. But is there a way to do it programmatically in VB.NET or C#?

```
I have tried the following with out success:

ReportParameterInfoCollection @params = default(ReportParameterInfoCollection);
@params = this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters();
List<ReportParameter> changedParams = new List<ReportParameter>();
foreach (ReportParameterInfo paramInfo in @params)
{
    ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter();
    param.Name = paramInfo.Name;
    if ((paramInfo.Name == "Terminal")
    {
        //param.Values.Add(User.Identity.Name);
        string[] values = new string[] { "Some Terminal", "Some Other Terminal" };
        param.Values.AddRange(values);
    }
    changedParams.Add(param);
}

this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(changedParams);
```

Comment: Have you tried sending the values as a comma-seperated list of values yet? Not sure if it'll work but worth a shot.

Comment: If your parameter is defined in report as multi value parameter (this part can't be changed from code) than your code should work properly.

Comment: I wish I could add a screen shot. Checked Multiple Options. Added items in list does not show up. The only difference is there is a check box to the "default" values that are on the report. There is nothing added from the c# code.

Comment: is there any available values set for a parameter?